# How to schedule a task every certain period of time

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to use JobScheduler as shown below , i would like to schedule a task every 1500 milli-seconds. when i run the below posted code, i receive the following
in the logCat:

```
E/JobServiceContext: Time-out while trying to bind com.example.pc_amr.twittertrendsnearlocation/.ActMain$JobSchedulerService jId=1, u0, dropping.
```

NOTE: the JobSchedulerService is created inside the ActMain activity

please let me know how to schedule a task every 11500 milli-seconds correctly and how to fix this error

**manifest**:

```
 <service
        android:name=".services.TwitterTrendsAPIService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"/>
 <service
        android:name=".ActMain$JobSchedulerService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

**code**:

```
this.mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    this.mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, JobSchedulerService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfoObj = new JobInfo.Builder(1, this.mComponentName).setPeriodic(1500).build();
    this.mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfoObj);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

   public JobSchedulerService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onStartJob"));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onStartJob"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is only 11500ms, the best answer is to use Handler :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 11500 ; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //ur code here
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `JobScheduler` has a minimum period of ~15 minutes or thereabouts. You cannot use `JobScheduler` to do work every 1.5 seconds.

Second, your `JobScheduler` is a nested class inside of an activity. That will not work. You would need it to be a `static` class or a standalone class.

There are a variety of ways to do work from your UI periodically, such as:

- `postDelayed()` on a `View`
- RxJava `Observable.interval()`
- `ScheduledExecutorService`

Whether any of those are appropriate depends a lot on the work that you were looking to do.

Comment: would you please provide a n exaple for Observable.timer

Comment: @LetsamrIt: Sorry, I meant `interval()` -- `timer()` is just for a one-shot event. https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/operators/IntervalExampleActivity.java contains an oddly-written example using `Observable.interval()`, and I am sure that there are others out there.